# PySerial Throwing 'NoneType' Exception During read()

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

I am using PySerial to read incoming bytes from a serial port into a buffer.  Every time I call my read function this exception gets thrown.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner  
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run  
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "gatewayTester.py", line 480, in mcuRead  
    byteIn = mcuPort.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 269, in read   
    win32.ResetEvent(self._overlapped_read.hEvent)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hEvent'
```

My application seems to work fine despite this exception being thrown.
However, I would like some clarity on the source of this issue.

Here is my serial read function.

```
def mcuRead(self, *args, **kwargs):

    global mcuPort
    global readVal
    global serialWriting
    global testRunning

    print("READING MCU")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    inBuffer = ""

    while testRunning:
        try:
            byteIn = ""
            if not mcuPort.is_open:
                mcuPort.open()

            #Read incoming byte 
            if not serialWriting:
                byteIn = mcuPort.read()
                inBuffer += byteIn
                #Skip newlines to parse incoming commands
                if(byteIn == "\n"):                     
                    inBuffer = ""

                #Check if buffer contains a valid command
                for rxCmd in mcuRxCmds:

                    if inBuffer == rxCmd['Command']:

                        #store incoming command globally
                        readVal = rxCmd['Command']
                        #Clear buffer
                        inBuffer = ""
                        print("MCU IN "+str(readVal))

        except(OSError, serial.SerialException):
            print(OSError)

        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Serial port is created globally as follows.  Read function is run concurrently on a separate thread.

```
mcuPort = serial.Serial(port, 115200, timeout=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells `mcuPort._overlapped_read`  is `None`!

```
win32.ResetEvent(self._overlapped_read.hEvent)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hEvent'
```

This is set in `def open`

```
try:
        self._overlapped_read = win32.OVERLAPPED()
        self._overlapped_read.hEvent = win32.CreateEvent(None, 1, 0, None)
```

Check if  `mcuPort._overlapped_read`  is **not** `None` after `mcuPort.open(...`

Beside this check if you have the latest `pySerial module`

Relevant:  [pywin32/bugs/search/?q=OVERLAPPED](https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/search/?q=OVERLAPPED)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was due to the asynchronous nature of how I was closing the port.  In my exit routine I closed the port before clearing 'testRunning'.  The loop would then go through one unstable iteration before completing.  Clearing the 'testRunning' lock before closing the port prevents this unstable iteration.

**Before**

```
def quitTest(self):

    global testRunning
    global mcuPort

    #Close all open ports
    if(mcuPort.is_open):
        mcuPort.close()


    testRunning = False
```

**After**

```
def quitTest(self):

    global testRunning
    global mcuPort


    testRunning = False

    #Close all open ports
    if(mcuPort.is_open):
        mcuPort.close()
```